# reporting mms agent to MMS service in amazon ec2

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, mongodb-mms

My db is on EC2 and i have installed MMS agent successfully and running successfully.
However, when i check from MMS Hosts, it says

```
You do not have a monitoring agent that is sending data to MMS or hosts configured.
```

when i look at the log... it says

```
2013-05-10 16:49:02,810 INFO Started agent parent process - version: 1.5.7
2013-05-10 16:49:07,996 INFO Starting agent process - version 1.5.7
2013-05-10 16:49:08,002 INFO Started agent process - parent pid: 1196 - version: 1.5.7
```

and seems running okay..
From MMS service when checking Agents section

```
ip-xx-xx-xx-xx  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx         12  1.5.7       05-10-13 - 10:11
```

it shows correctly.

Is there some kind of firewall issue or outbound setting that I need to go through? Please help...

(Update)
I get this when i try to telenet from EC2 instance... seems like i can telnet to mms.10gen.com

```
telnet mms.10gen.com 443
Trying 75.101.156.xxx...
Connected to mms.10gen.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

(Another update)
This is what i got from the agent log .. seems like i am getting database connection issue?

```
Problem collecting non-blocking data from: 54.215.108.xxx:27017 - exception: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/root/deploy/versions/p4n_config/master/p4n_config/resources/mms-agent/nonBlockingStats.py", line 56, in run monitorConn = self.mmsAgent.getDbConnection( self.hostKey ) File "/root/deploy/versions/p4n_config/master/p4n_config/resources/mms-agent/mmsAgent.py", line 109, in getDbConnection return pymongo.Connection( hostDef['mongoUri'] , slave_okay=True, ssl=True, document_class=bson.son.SON ) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/connection.py", line 220, in __init__ max_pool_size, document_class, tz_aware, _connect, **kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 336, in __init__ raise ConnectionFailure(str(e)) ConnectionFailure: could not connect to 54.215.108.xxx:27017: timed out
```

Comment: you have to add the host ( mongoDB ) information, in the MMS UI interface giving the proper credentials for admin database. Then the plot should show up in next 10-15 mins.

Comment: even if i add host, i get

    No data has been collected for this host by the agent.

Comment: This question would be better asked in the [`mongodb-mms` community forum](https://groups.google.com/group/10gen-mms).  If you can include a link to your MMS group (only 10gen staff can view the details) someone would be better able to help.  If it has been more than 15 minutes since adding your new host I would suggest checking your [Agent Log](https://mms.10gen.com/#agentLogsTab) tab in MMS to see if there are any relevant errors there.

Comment: Are the MMS agent and the MongoDB server on the same instance or separate instances?

Comment: Same instance....

and i get errors like this

Problem collecting blocking data from: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017 -ConnectionFailure: could not connect to xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017: timed out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... here's what solved my problem..
my mongodb and agent were in the same instance. I had to open 27017 (port being used for my mongodb) for the inbound connection from aws console and that solved.

for example if my ec2 elastic ip was 1.1.1.1 
in security group, i added 1.1.1.1/32 port 27017. and that just solved my problem. Kind of weird, but that helped.

Comment: try telnet to that db machine from the machine installed with agent.